# Clear only a part of the screen in turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm using turtle graphics and I would like to clear only a part of the screen and keep the rest of the image/drawings intact.

So far I've been drawing a white rectangle to clear a part of the image, but this is very slow and if the background isn't white then I can't use this method.

This is the function I have been using :

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()

def screen_clearer(coordinate_x, coordinate_y, length, width):
    t.up()
    t.goto(coordinate_x, coordinate_y)
    t.color("white")
    t.begin_fill()
    t.setheading(0)
    for i in range(2):
        t.fd(length)
        t.rt(90)
        t.fd(width)
        t.rt(90)
    t.end_fill()
```

Is there a built-in function in turtle that clears only part of the screen? I have looked and haven't found anything so this is why I've been using this.

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: Thanks, I was quite sure it wasn't possible

Comment: I ended up using your solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One rough way to do this is to use different turtles to draw different parts of the screen.  When you're ready, you can have one or more turtles `clear()` or `.undo()` their portion of the screen:

```
from time import sleep
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("cyan")

left = Turtle(visible=False)
left.color("white")

right = Turtle(visible=False)
right.color("red")

left.penup()
left.goto(-200, -150)
left.pendown()

left.circle(150, 720, steps=5)

right.penup()
right.goto(200, -175)
right.pendown()

right.circle(175, 360, steps=6)

sleep(3)

left.clear()  # or: while left.undobufferentries(): left.undo()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will indeed use multiple turtles to clear different parts of the screen

Answer (score -1):

To delete your last line move back on it with the pen in screen color. For instance, on a white screen:
color("black"); forward(100)
color("white"); back(100)